# Connection between Lie Theory and differential Galois theory.

Tags: galois-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I would like to know if there exists a relationship between Lie theory ( Lie groups and Lie algebras ) and Linear differential equations through Differential Galois theory.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking; the original motivation for Lie theory were differential equations.

Comment: Yes. The "Galois groups" of differential equations are Lie groups. You should browse, for example, Majid's beautifully written book on differential Galois theory.

Comment: @quid, the appearance of Lie groups in differential Galois theory is of a rather different spirit than how they show up in Lie's theory (as described in Oliver's book, for example)

Comment: @quid @ Mariano Suarez-Alvarez : Majid's book never treate Lie groups, only algebraic groups. I'm looking for an analytic version of the theory of Linear differential equations through Lie theory? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications (also to @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez ) You might want to include this information in the body of the post via an [edit]